# How do I connect (and use content of) an RDF file in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, rdf

I'm working on a prototype in flex and I need to connect my application to an .RDF file that contains some properties. I need to use and manipulate those properties in a "descriptor file" made in Actionscript. So my question is: how do I connect my flex application to that .RDF file?
Thanks,

regards

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If RDF is represented in its XML form (which I guess is the most common anyway), you can simply treat it as XML and use the built-in `XML` and `XMLList` classes, and the rather convenient E4X (ECMAScript for XML) syntax to traverse your document. To load the RDF file from the server or from another remote location, use the `URLLoader` class.

If, on the other hand, the RDF uses some other representation, you'll probably have to do the parsing from plaintext yourself.  (You can still use `URLLoader`).